# How to set PieChart location in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, pie-chart

In relation to the last question I asked (context not important), I'm trying to implement CSS styling and the PieChart class into a program. I have a small problem, however. I can't seem to change the position of the PieChart using any methods. I'm not quite sure how to go from here, my example code is below:

```
import javafx.scene.Group; //Maybe too many imports, I just use em all
import javafx.scene.Scene; //because I'm lazy
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class AnimatingDemo extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        //Create PieChart and data for PieChart
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(data);
        PieChart.Data one = new PieChart.Data("one", 50.0);
        PieChart.Data two = new PieChart.Data("two", 33.0);
        PieChart.Data three = new PieChart.Data("three", 17.0);
        data.addAll(one, two, three);

        //create root group
        Group root = new Group();
        //set up window
        //add nodes to root
        root.getChildren().addAll(pieChart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,500);
        stage.setTitle("Testing arc animation");
        stage.setScene(scene);luck
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

What I want to know is how I can change the position of the PieChart, I tried looking for the answer myself for a few hours with no luck. Although the solution is likely simple, I can't find it myself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Replace the `Group` with an appropriate [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) that lays the pie chart out where you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `setLayoutX` and `setLayoutY`? In your case it will be something like that `pieChart.setLayoutX(-100);` to move chart to the left.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thank you very much